# QField primary key error: Help with setting a primary key for a KML imported as a Vector Layer

Tags: qgis, layers, kml, error, qfield

I have a KML file (Generated in google earth), which I would like to import into QGIS and display in QField.

I have Layer -> Add Layer -> (File+automatic) and my KML. (No problems to this point).
However when I attempt to upload my layers to QField I get an error message(see below).

I imagine it simple to "allocate" a field as the primary key.
I have set up a new field called "my_id" based on $ID, and it has a sequential unique identifier.

How do I make my primary key "my_id". What am I missing?

Error Message:
Missing primary key. QFieldCloud supports only layers with a defined single-column primary key. Please change the layer action to "Remove" in "Layer Properties -> QField".

Comment: I don't really know, but I believe the PK is generally called 'fid'. You may
want to try that.